# Fill Listbox with System.IO.File.ReadAllLines and a vaiable Filename c#

Tags: c#, file.readalllines

im learning c# and started to Programm a tool for my own.

I fill some listboxes with a TextBox and save this listbox to a txt file.
This works fine with: System.IO.File.WriteAllText

When i start the Programm again, the listboxes will fill direct from the txt file, this also works.

```
 string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("PWTool_Save.txt");

 foreach (string line in lines){.....}
```

But now i want to make the Savefiles dynamic.
They have now the Name

```
string sPath = "PWTool_Save_"+user1+".txt";
System.IO.File.WriteAllText("PWTool_Save_" +user1+".txt", string.Empty);
System.IO.StreamWriter SaveFile = new System.IO.StreamWriter(sPath);
```

Save the file dynamic works fine, but load the file dynamic dont works.

Example:

I save the file with the Name

```
string user1 = "Tom"
"PWTool_Save_" +user1+".txt"
```

> PWTool_Save_Tom.txt

Now when i try to load it with

```
 string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("PWTool_Save_"+user1+".txt");
```

it dont works, but when i manually say filename is

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("PWTool_Save_Tom.txt");
```

it works :(

can someone help me? sorry for bad english

Comment: Have you added a breakpoint at the ReadAllLines line and checked if user1 is in fact saying "Tom" ?

Comment: Please be more specific than "doesn't work". Is the file empty? Is there an error?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp, sorry, no, there is no error, the listbox i want to load just stay empty